# Remove rows from the current context

Tags: powerpivot

I have a problem that nags me for a couple of days …

My problem is about people (dimSomeOne) who try something (dimThing) on a certain day (dimDate).Each try is finished with a status (dimStatus). It is possible that a distinct person has 1 or more trys for the same thing on the same date. This can be seen for the 19th of march, here someone 1 has tried 2times the thing A, and finished with the status 1.
What I'm looking for is the number of distinct SOMEONES on specific day for a specific status. If SOMEONE achieves different status on the same day, this person is just counted for his MAX status.

For the context dimTraining:A and dimDate:20.03.2015 there are 5 active rows:theRowNumber 3,4,5,8,11I want to remove the rows 3,4,5 due to the fact that they "belong" to someone 1 and the fact that someone 1 has the max stauts of 3 on that date.

I'm able to produce a DAX query that returns the a result that has the correct number of someone's for the the date and the status

```
evaluate(
summarize(
filter(
    addcolumns(
        summarize(
            'fact',[aDate],[someone],[aStatus]
            --,[theRowNumber]
        )
    ,"maxstatus"
    ,calculate(max(fact[aStatus]),all(fact[aStatus]))
    )
,fact[aStatus] = [maxstatus]
)
,[aDate],[someone],[aStatus],[maxStatus]
--,[therownumber]
)
)
order by
[aDate],[someone],[aStatus]
```

, but I'm not able to use this in calculated measure.
As always any help is appreciated

By the way Here is a xlsx file that contains my sample data and there are also two measures that unfortunately do not solve my problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/anxn0vmrjzpiewx/TheDistinctSomeOneThing.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally did the trick is to add a calculated column that results to the curerent status, if the current status is valid (for someone, on a thing at, at a given day), if this is not the case than the formula returns a NULL value using the function [BLANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634820.aspx):

```
validStatus=IF([aStatus]=CALCULATE(MAX([aStatus]); FILTER(fact; [aThing]=EARLIER([aThing]) && [someone]=EARLIER([someone]) && [aDate]=EARLIER([aDate])));[aStatus];blank())
```

Then I use a quite simple calculated measure that uses [DISTINCTCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx) on fact[someone], with a little filtering. The filter is necessary due to the fact that active rows for the current filter context still contain rows with an invalid status (NULL)

expected

```
distinctCountSomeOne=calculate(distinctcount(fact[someone])
;not(isblank(fact[ValidStatus])))
```

This leads to the following ...

[image]

Please be aware that between this post and my initial question I have added a row to the table dimSomeOne and to the table fact (the newSomeOne for athing:1 on dimDate:2015-03-20 with dimStatus:2 to demonstrate the maybe unexpected behavior of the DAX function [DISTINCTCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx).

And here is a [link to my question on the PowerPivot](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/820da7ec-9db4-4447-8229-732f6e1d8e3f/remove-active-rows-from-a-filter-context?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) forum, thanks to Imke reminding me of the good use of calculated columns ...

Comment: Thanks for posting what worked for you. In order to better help others with the same situation, it's better to expand on the details of the link, as links don't always hang around forever.